# runOnUiThread inside a widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, ui-thread

I want to make an HTTP Request inside the app widget I've built.

The idea is that every couple of hours the widget will update itself by making an HTTP Request and use the information of it to update its views.

I've already tried to use a `Thread` in `onUpdate` function, the HTTP Request is working just fine, the problem is that I can't use `runOnUiThread()` to update the views, because I have no parent activity to run this function on.

Is there another way to update the widget's views inside the `Thread`?

Sample code:

```
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        final int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_card);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              try {
                 Http.Response resp = Http.postData("http://www.example.com", null, null, null);
                 views.setTextViewText(R.id.textview, resp.body);
              }
              catch (Exception ex) {
                  Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Thank you upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already tried to use a Thread in onUpdate function

That is not a very good idea. Your process can be terminated before your work completes. Instead, create an `IntentService` that does the network I/O and updates the app widget via an `AppWidgetManager`.

> the problem is that I can't use runOnUiThread() to update the views, because I have no parent activity to run this function on

Since you do not have any views to update, you do not need to worry about this. You can set up the `RemoteViews` and hand them to the `AppWidgetManager` on a background thread.